# Set declined to True if approved is False

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a project that allows student to apply to borrow book from a library and then the librarian decides to approve or decline the request.

**models.py**

```
class PendingRequest(models.Model):
    book_request = models.ForeignKey(Borrow, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    declined = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approval_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

I am using a `modelformset_factory` to render out the form to update multiple instance of the above model. What i want to achieve is to be able to set `declined` field to **True** and `approved` to **False** whenever the librarian doesn't approve the request

**views.py**

```
def approve(request, pk):
    member = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
    pending_requests = PendingRequest.objects.filter(member=member)
    PendingRequestFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        PendingRequest, form=ApproveForm, extra=0
    )
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = PendingRequestFormSet(request.POST, queryset=pending_requests)
        approved = request.POST.get(formset.prefix + "-approved")
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.book_request = instance.book_request
                instance.member = instance.member
                instance.book = instance.book
                instance.save()
    else:
        formset = PendingRequestFormSet(queryset=pending_requests)
    context = {"formset": formset, "member": member}
    return render(request, "books/approve.html", context)
```

**form.py**

```
class ApproveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    approved = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = PendingRequest
        fields = [
            "approved",
            "book",
        ]
```

**template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Approve Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Update Pending Requests for {{ member.username }}</h1>

    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %} 
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Book</th>
            <th>Approved</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for form in formset %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{form.book}}</td>
            <td>{{form.approved}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
    <style>
      select {
        appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      select {
        pointer-events: none;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should improve your db model. `approved` and `not_approved` doesn't make much sense since the information could be stored in one field. You can go even further and only use `approval_date` and remove `approved` and `not_approved`. `approval_date` will be `None` as long the object is not approved.

Comment: What do you mean by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our friend in comments meant that `approved` and `declined` fields are mutually exclusive. You only need one of them to indicate that specific status.

```
class PendingRequest(models.Model):
    ...
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    declined = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Related to you question. Form is not validating because id field is required, so add them in:

forms.py

```
class ApproveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    approved = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = PendingRequest
        fields = [
            "id",
            "approved",
            "book",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "id": forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

and also in templates.py

```
...
<tbody>
  {% for form in formset %}
  <tr>
    {{form.id}}
    <td>{{form.book}}</td>
    <td>{{form.approved}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
...
```

and views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = PendingRequestFormSet(request.POST, queryset=pending_requests)
    for form in formset:
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['approved']:
                form.save()
```

That will set `approved` field to `True` or `False` on update click. If you want to maintain `declined` field then just add to `forms.pt` as a hidden field using the same process, although I would recommend to remove it.